# php - mysql UPDATE error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form that will update data in a mysql table, although I not sure what the problem is.

Here's the php for the form itself

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="20" value="anonymous"><br>
Image (Optional): <input type="text" name="image" placeholer="Enter an image URL!"> -     Leave blank for no Image<br>
Text:<br><textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="text" placeholder="Enter some text!"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here's the update.php page

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("Host","User","Password","Database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Oh noes! a MySql error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $_POST["name"];
$text = $_POST["text"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$sql = 'UPDATE saveddata SET username="$name", image="$image", text="$text" WHERE 1';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if($res){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php' />";
}
else{
    echo "Sorry, something wrong happend, try again!";
}

?>
```

I'm not sure why, but, I get the error "Sorry, something wrong happend, try again!".

Comment: The issue really isn't a MySQL UPDATE error (apart from the fact that if your statement did run successfully, it would update every flipping row in the table.) It's some code that won't work (mixing mysqli and mysql functions), and if the string substitution issue is fixed, it will be a gaping SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong in a lot of ways:

- You are mixing mysql and mysqli;
- You are using variables inside a single quoted string so they will not get expanded;
- If you get your variables inside your query, you will be introducing an sql injection vulnerability;
- If you get your sql query to work, you will be updating all rows in the table.

You should use mysqli (or PDO) and switch to prepared statements with bound variables.

Comment: [Mysqli - Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! If I could give reputation, I would!

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix **mysqli** and **mysql** interface functions.

You're connecting with **`mysqli_connect`**, but then using **`mysql_query`**.

You'd need to use **`mysqli_query`** function.

Also, you should either be using prepared statements with bind placeholders, or be using the **`mysqli_real_escape_string`** function to close a gaping SQL Injection vulnerability.

I doubt your intention is to update all of the rows in the table, and set them all to literal values that start with a dollar sign. More likely you wanted to insert a single row, and use the values of the variables, e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO saveddata (`username`, `image`, `text`) VALUES ('"
     . mysqli_real_escape_string($username) . "','" 
     . mysqli_real_escape_string($image) . "','" 
     . mysqli_real_escape_string($text) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put $con and use `mysqli_query` in the update since you're using mysqli in your connection instead of mysql.

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Take note that `mysql_query` is deprecated. Better to stick in `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysqli connection so use mysqli_query() and pass connection link like this :

```
<?php 

 $sql = "UPDATE saveddata SET username='".$name."', image='".$image."', text='".$text."' WHERE 1";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

?>
```